# Java regex positive lookahead

Tags: java, regex

I've been having problems generating a regex for a particular string.

My source string is basically a set of key-value pairs. My desired output is to 
Here is a sample string:

```
:27B:Hello: World!
     Something
     World: Hello
:29A:Test
:30:Something isn't right-}
```

Desired output:

```
Key: 27B  Value: Hello: World!
     Something
     World: Hello
Key: 29A  Value: Test
Key: 30   Value: Something isn't right
```

And here is my regex for it so far:

```
(\\d+\\w?):([\\w\\d\\s'/,:\\Q.()\\E]+(?=(:\\s*\\d+\\w?:|\\-\\})))
```

The problem is that i seem to be capturing the entire message.

```
   e.g. Key: 27B Value:Hello: World!
         Something
         World: Hello
    :29A:Test
    :30:Something isn't right
```

What should my regex be so that i could extract these key/value pairs?

Comment: It is not clear what is allowed and what is not allowed in your keys and values. I don't think there is anyway for `!` to be matched in the value part for your current regex.

Comment: Are you trying to capture the key and values or print the string as described in your desired output example? It would also be useful to know how you are using the regex. `Pattern` + `Matcher.find()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is greedy, so `[\\w\\d\\s'/,:\\Q.()\\E]+` will capture all characters up to the *last* point in the string at which the lookahead can match.  To grab only up to the *first* such point you would need to use the "reluctant" version `+?` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":(\\d+\\w?):((?:[^:-]|:(?!\\d+\\w?:)|-(?!\\}))+)(?:-}[\\S\\s]*)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find())
    System.out.print("Key: " + m.group(1) + " Value: " + m.group(2));
```

Produces your desired output. The last optional group is to consume `-}` and anything after it. Basically finds the key and then consumes all characters until it hits another key.

**Edit:**

If you want something more true to your original regex you can use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\w?):(.+?(?=(:\\s*\\d+\\w?:|\\-\\})))",Pattern.DOTALL);
```