# Regex to replace attributes of style from an HTML string

Tags: java, html, regex

I want a regex which removes a list of attributes from within the style attribute of a given html tag.

Ex : i want to remove height and cursor from span tag.

I/P:

```
String htmlFragment ="<span id=\"nav-askquestion\" style=\"width:200px;cursor:default;height:100px;\" name="questions"> <b>hh</b></span>";
```

O/P

```
<span id="nav-askquestion" style="width:200px;" name="questions"><b>hh</b></span>
```

I have the following regex but it removes all occurrences height and cursor, not just inside div

```
String cleanString=htmlFragment.replaceAll("(height|cursor)[ ]*:[ ]*[^;]+;","");
```

**Not looking to use html parser for this due to specific requirement.**

Comment: I will strongly suggest to not to use RegEx for this. You should look at the HTML/XML parsers for parsing the tags and data and then do the operations.

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1553851)

Comment: To only replace that in a certain <div>, you will have to make a RegEx search to find all the <div>s, then inside those select which ones to modify, and then to modify them. You cannot use only one RegEx for this.

Comment: Even when you think a parsing case is too “simple” to worry about the consequences of using regular expressions, it often isn’t.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with others that it would be better to use HTML/XML parsers, which allow you to drill down to specific elements without worrying about any "accidental" regex matches.

However, having read Xlsx's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643231/regex-to-replace-attributes-of-style-from-an-html-string#comment70486814_41643231), "*You cannot use only one RegEx for this.*" I was compelled to post this solution using captured groups. This is purely for demonstration purposes only

```
String reg = "(<span.+)((height|cursor) *:[^;]+;)(.*)((height|cursor) *:[^;]+;)(.*)";

String cleanString=htmlFragment.replaceAll(reg, "$1$4$7");
```

Obviously, it is not pretty and it may still match on some HTML content (as opposed to tags), but it is possible. Unless this is intended as a quick fix, I urge you to use a more appropriate solution as suggested by others. One possible solution would be [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
\s*(height|cursor)\s*:\s*.+?\s*;\s*
```

You can test it out [here](http://regexr.com/).

If there are other attributes besides height and cursor, you want to capture, you can just keep adding bars between them (background-color|height|font-size) etc.

Comment: I wrote something similar , the issue is I want to remove some attributes from within the style attribute only . So if it's <div style= 'height:50px;color:red;width:100px' >hello </div>. Output should be <div style= 'color:red; >hello </div>.

Comment: Does java regex support positive look behinds?  http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: It does to some extent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340662/java-regex-positive-lookahead

Comment: Well, then maybe you can add a positive look-behind that makes sure the match is preceded by style="[^"]+ (in other words a an unclosed quote of a style attribute).

Answer (score 0):

As I said before, I will strongly suggest to not to use RegEx for this and make use of HTML/XML parsers for parsing the tags and data and then do all your operations.

But if you don't want to do that for some reason then I would suggest you to fallback to the basic sub-string based methods rather than using `RegEx`.

Here is a sample code snippet for the above situation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String htmlFragment = "<span id=\"nav-askquestion\" style=\"width:200px;cursor:default;height:100px;\" name=\"questions\"> <b>hh</b></span>";
    int startIndex = htmlFragment.indexOf("<span");
    int stopIndex = htmlFragment.indexOf("</span>") + 7;

    /* Cursor */
    int cursorStart = htmlFragment.indexOf("cursor:", startIndex);
    int cursorEnd = htmlFragment.indexOf(";", cursorStart);
    htmlFragment = new StringBuilder()
            .append(htmlFragment.substring(startIndex, cursorStart))
            .append(htmlFragment.substring(cursorEnd + 1, stopIndex))
            .toString();

    /* Update Indices */
    stopIndex = htmlFragment.indexOf("</span>") + 7;

    /* Height */
    int heightStart = htmlFragment.indexOf("height:", startIndex);
    int heightEnd = htmlFragment.indexOf(";", heightStart);
    htmlFragment = new StringBuilder()
            .append(htmlFragment.substring(startIndex, heightStart))
            .append(htmlFragment.substring(heightEnd + 1, stopIndex))
            .toString();

    /* Output */
    System.out.println(htmlFragment);
}
```

I know it looks a bit messy but that's the only way I could think of.

Comment: StringBuilder is overkill for the one-time concatenation of two strings.  It provides no benefit while reducing readability.